# Force breaking from a loop in Pycharm debugger

Tags: python, loops, exception, debugging, pycharm

I would like to know if it is possible to break from a loop using the Pycharm debugger (python). I am debugging machine learning code and sometimes I would prefer to avoid executing entirely the long running loops that are located in library code. One or two iterations suffice.

I tried stopping at a breakpoint and executing python commands like `break`, `raise StopIteration()` but they either throw an error or don't do anything.

Maybe there is a button somewhere to throw exceptions? Or another command?

Edit: So, it is possible to stop at a breakpoint in the loop, right click outside of the loop and use the "Jump To Cursor" command to escape the loop. Unfortunately, in the library code with the loop I want to avoid, there is no line after the loop to jump to, and it doesn't seem possible to jump to the implicit return statement.